# Pendulum animation on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i face trouble to apply pendulum animation base gravity effect on my UIImageView. can any buddy help me to come out from this trouble??

i have tried below source code. but in that gravitational force  is not apply.

```
- (void)swingPendulum {
 pendulum.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0);

[pendulum.layer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI*3/4, 0, 0, 1)];
CABasicAnimation *needleAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
needleAnim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
needleAnim.duration = 1;
needleAnim.repeatCount = 5;
needleAnim.autoreverses = YES;
// Setting fillMode means that, once the animation finishes, the needle stays in its end position.
needleAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
needleAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
needleAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI*3/4];
 [pendulum.layer addAnimation:needleAnim forKey:nil];
}
```

actually we need animation like...

check out this : http://blog.ruben-martins.co.uk/2010/02/maya-tutorials-pendulum-animation.html

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i have tried almost all animation. but i think i need to apply mathematical formula for gravitational force..

Answer (score 0):

If you've got an image with a blank top section and starts in the middle and just want to rotate it (haven't tried it tho):

```
-(void) doAnimation {

    imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.7);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{

        imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.7);

    } completion:^{

        [self doAnimation];

    }]
```

Comment: Hi jjv360, I was wondering if you can tell me what the one-liner that enables the scrolling gestures of UIScrollView in the container UIView is. You told me about when you comments in a question of mine. I'm looking for it now but I deleted that question not long ago. So it would be great if you can answer this question below. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134684/uiscrollview-inside-uiview-uiview-gesture-one-liner