# UIScrollView inside UIView, UIView gesture one-liner

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a `UIScrollView` inside a `UIView`. For customized paging purpose I have set the clipping of this `UIScrollView` to No so the `UIScrollView` still shows up in Region A and Region B of the `UIView`.

> [ region A [UIScrollView] region B ]

Now I want Region A B to be able to trigger scroll events of the `UIScrollView's` when touched.. I remember there is an one liner (something like `[X addGestureRecognizer ...]`) that does the trick but I've forgotten what it is... It would be great if someone can tell me what that is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect the `UIScrollView`'s scrolling gestures to another view, you can do this:

```
[paddingView addGestureRecognizer:scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Yeah this is the one... So it is `panGesureRecognizer`.. I've mistaken it as something else.. Will upvote when my votes are available :)

Comment: Waouh ! I didn't knew about this. It's really great and seems to work perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This won't let you have a fluid control on your scrolling, like the one you get from the `UIScrollView`.

However, you can use this code :

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewSwiped:)];
[leftSwipeGestureRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipeGestureRecognizer];
[leftSwipeGestureRecognizer release];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewSwiped:)];
[rightSwipeGestureRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeGestureRecognizer];
[rightSwipeGestureRecognizer release];
```

firing this method :

```
- (void)viewSwiped:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGestureRecognizer {
    switch (swipeGestureRecognizer.direction) {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
            // Make your scroll view scroll
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
            // Make your scroll view scroll
            break;
        default:
            // Do Nothing
            break;
    }
}
```

It will allow you to retrieve the swipes gestures and page your `UIScrollView` accordingly.

Two other solutions might be better :

1. You could use the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` the same way as above. It recognizes real pan gestures and not only discrete swipes but the implementation of the sync between your finger and the `UIScrollView` will be slightly more complicated.
2. You could let your `UIScrollView` take the total width of the `UIView` and manage the paging by yourself, recalculating your steps while tracking the current state of the `UIScrollView` via `UIScrollViewDelegate`. Again, a bit harder.

Hope this will help,

Comment: Thanks!! I was looking for a one-liner though.. But it looks great!  I'll upvote it when I've got the vote! Currently I used up all votes...